# How can I add "Bid.Price" into a vector on R (with TrueFX library)

Tags: r, vector

I'm using TrueFX library in R, so I do that:

```
(QueryTrueFX(ConnectTrueFX("USD/CAD,EUR/JPY", 'user', 'pass', format='csv'), parse.response=TRUE))


    Symbol Bid.Price Ask.Price      High      Low      Open           TimeStamp
1 USD/CAD   1.31732   1.31737   1.31092   1.3191   1.31407 2018-09-07 18:25:01
2 EUR/JPY 128.43300 128.44000 128.01300 129.1150 128.68200 2018-09-07 18:25:01
```

So, I want to assign "Bid.Price" into a vector called Bid (Bid<- ...)
How can I do that?

Thanks for answers :)

Comment: What object does the `QueryTrueFX` call return? Is it a `.csv` file? A `data.frame`?

Comment: Yes, it’s a data frame with .csv format, but I can chose .phyton too.

Comment: If you do:
`data <- QueryTrueFX(ConnectTrueFX("USD/CAD,EUR/JPY", 'user', 'pass', format='csv'), parse.response=TRUE)`
would `data$Bid.Price` give you what you want?

Comment: Yeah! It works!
Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Question was solved in comments.

Since `QueryTrueFX` returns a `data.frame` if `parse.response = TRUE` or `pretty = TRUE` (see [documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TFX/versions/0.1.0/topics/ConnectTrueFX)), the solution was as simple as

```
data <- QueryTrueFX(ConnectTrueFX("USD/CAD,EUR/JPY", 'user', 'pass', format='csv'),
                    parse.response=TRUE)
data$Bid.Price
```